# Tomcat Replacing VM arguments

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, configuration, jvm-arguments

this may be a stupid question:

I currently have some VM arguments that my web application requires. They are something like:

```
-Dcom.company.custom.var='test'
```

And I access them in code with:

```
System.getProperty("com.company.custom.config")
```

I would like to move them into one of the tomcat xml files (server.xml, context.xml, etc) but I'm not sure how I would go about doing that.

So my question is two parts. Where (and how) should I put these variables into xml and how do I access them in code?

Thanks in advance and sorry if this has already been answered. My search-fu on this topic has failed me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Officially, all JVM options go either to `setenv.sh` (for Unix) or `setenv.bat` (for Windows).  This file [is not present by default](http://www.tomcatexpert.com/ask-the-experts/configure-tomcat-memory-settings) in Tomcat but if you create one, it will be picked up by startup script.

The reason why you should be using this instead of `server.xml` is that `server.xml` might change from one Tomcat version to another but `setenv.sh` (or .bat) is completely custom to you.

Reading this value is, as you pointed out, through `System.getProperty(...)`.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into doing it this way.

Answer (score 2):

If these are app-specific configuration items, the standard location for it is a `<context-param>` in `web.xml`. Something like this:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>myvar</param-name>
    <param-value>value</param-value>
</context-param>
```

You can access these values from code using [`ServletContext#getInitParameter(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getInitParameter%28java.lang.String%29). From inside a servlet, you could write something like:

```
String myvar = getServletContext().getInitParameter("myvar");
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. They are not application specific. Could I put them in the tomcat/conf/web.xml ?

Comment: I'll try it out. If it works I'll mark your answer as correct. Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: This didn't quite work out for me since some of my classes where I'm using System.getProperty don't have visibility to ServletContext. Thanks for the info anyway.