# How to add VM arguments to Tomcat Embedded Starter

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat8, embedded-tomcat-8

I use Tomcat Starter for starting my web application like that:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ServletException, LifecycleException {
    Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();
    tomcat.setBaseDir("temp");
    tomcat.setPort(8080);
    String contextPath = "/mypath";
    String warFilePath = "C:\\myproject\\target\\myapp.war";
    tomcat.getHost().setAppBase(".");

    tomcat.addWebapp(contextPath, warFilePath);
    tomcat.start();
    tomcat.getServer().await();
}
```

It works, but if I want to pass a VM argument (e.g. -Duser.language=en) to server, I cannot do it. 
I tried ContextEnvironment, ApplicationParameter, ...
I cannot find any reference documentation or question for this topic.

Can you help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tomcat Replacing VM arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12372550/tomcat-replacing-vm-arguments)

Comment: i don't think you can set environment variable through a program and also it doesn't make sense because you want the environment to be created before you program starts execution.